# Загрузка изображения

Tags: objective-c, ios

У меня картинка в приложении загружается в `UIImageView` через `URL`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы она была вложенной в программе? Т.е. хранилась в самой программе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каком формате хотите хранить картинку, в `jpeg` или `png`? Для обоих есть вариант сохранения.

```
// Путь для хранения ваших файлов.
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/картинка.png"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/картинка.jpg"];

// качество сжатия для картинки диапазон от 0.0-1.0
// создаем файл ЖПГ
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

// создаем файл ПНГ
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

P.S. `image` - это Ваша картинка из интернета.

Comment: > [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/картинка.png"]  
  
Из вопроса не очень понятно, но, может быть, @Sergey4590 имел в виду, что картинка *изначально* хранится в программе?

Comment: Ну как бэ если она там хранится зачем тогда ее сохранять? Ну тогда необходимо уточнение где она хранится, в NSBundle или на сервере, или в какойто директории приложения?

Comment: @x86-64 а у топикстартера нигде не сказано, что ему *надо что-то сохранять*.

Comment: Ой ну не начинайте, человек спросил как ее хранить, я ответил. Есть еще претензии?

Comment: @x86-64 :) да я не придираюсь, просто мне непонятна была сама формулировка вопроса.  
P.S. прощу прощения, прочитал заголовок вопроса. Мозг уже сам по себе фильтрует видимо "ненужные данные".

Comment: Свой субъективный вывод о сохранении картинки из интернета я сделал на анализе прошлых вопросов, которые были заданы участником  Sergey4590. 
З.Ы. нечего страшного у самого такое бывает :)